# After logging in with jwt and getting access to protected page and closing tab and opening new tab with I am getting access to protected page

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

What my code should do : In login Page , after logging in I am getting access to protected page but after deleting current the tab and opening new tab and hitting endpoint of protected page I shouldn't  get access to that protected page

Problem or Issue : After logging in I am getting access to protected page ,but when I the close tab  and opening new tab and hitting the endpoint of protected page I am getting access to protected page even the JWT is not stored in cookie , an the JWT of last logged in user is getting access in console

Code for validating credential and generating JWT when logging in :

```
    app.post('/login/recorded',async(req,res)=>{
    // const loginUser= new RegistrationModel();
    const findData=await RegisterationModel.findOne({email:req.body.email});
    try{
        console.log(findData);
        if(findData==={}){
            res.send("not found");
        }
        if(findData.email===req.body.email && findData.password===req.body.password){
            const token = await findData.generateAuthToken();
            res.cookie('jwt',token,{
                httpOnly:true // you cant delete manually
            });
            // console.log(`cookie : ${req.cookies.jwt}`);
            res.redirect('/index');
            console.log(token)
            // res.send("you are logged in");
        }
        else{
            res.send("invalid");
            
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);

    }
})
```

Code for authenticating the JWT when generated during logging and stored in cookie :

```
    const auth =async(req,res,next)=>{
    try{
        console.log("auth")
        // console.log(token);
    const token=req.cookies.jwt;
    const verifyUser=jwt.verify(token,'helloworld');
    const user=await RegisterationModel.findOne({_id:verifyUser._id});
    // console.log(user);
    console.log(verifyUser);
    res.cookie('jwt',' ',{maxAge:1});
    next();
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(401).send(error);
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

code for secret page route :

```
app.get('/secretpage',auth,(req,res)=>{
res.render('secret');
```

})

code for index .hbs

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index Filee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/secretpage">Secret Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check in the browser to make sure that the cookie doesn't present before sending the request to server? Cookie isn't deleted when you close browser tabs.

Answer (score 0):

> After logging in I am getting access to protected page ,but when I the
> close tab and opening new tab and hitting the endpoint of protected
> page I am getting access to protected page even the JWT is not stored
> in cookie

From the code, it seems you are reading the JWT token from a cookie only. Now, you should check the console under Application > Cookies and delete the cookie associated with your application. It will work as expected.

Also, in your code, why do you need to check the user when you are verifying the token?

```
 const verifyUser=jwt.verify(token,'helloworld');
 const user=await RegisterationModel.findOne({_id:verifyUser._id}); // no need to make sure user exist in auth middleware.
```

You don't need to check if the user exists in DB or not in the auth middleware, create a new one and follow the subsequent steps for your app flow.

I recommend you check [this](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-build-authentication-api-with-jwt-token-in-nodejs/) link to know how JWT should be made and sent it to client correctly.

Comment: Please neglect my saving user data from db and other thing is after opening new tab my cookie is stored in new tab too which is of   user how logged in from last logged in from other tab .. what should I do to delete that cookie ? and One more thing Do stored another tab when the tab is closed from which user logged in . ?

Comment: cookies are shared among browser tabs, go to the above path see your cookie name, jwt, delete it.

Comment: so you are telling after user get logged in I should write a code res.delete in auth function after verifying cookie to delete the cookie?

Comment: No, You need to understand how JWT authentication works. When you create a cookie, it attaches to every request by default and you can read the same cookie until you delete it or modify its content. Also, JWT has an expiration in order to create a new token or refresh token. I recommend you first check how things work in order to implement a correct way of using JWT token.